# getIntExtra in ViewModel android

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I have been trying to convert this small project to MVVM, where i switch the json file based on the previous activity, but i cannot use this intent.getIntExtra in ViewModel. how do i achieve that, the code given below is the one i wrote in the activity class, but i can't do
intent.getIntExtra in viemodel. I am new to MVVM i want to use the ame function in viewModel class

```html
private fun loadAllQuestions(){
        var jsonStr: String? = null

        if(intent.getIntExtra("FROM", 0) == 0){
             jsonStr = "mcq1.json".loadJSONFromAsset()
        }
        else if(intent.getIntExtra("FROM", 1) == 1){
             jsonStr = "mcq2.json".loadJSONFromAsset()

        }
```

Comment: If using Hilt, you can use `@Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle` in the constructor or you can create a custom `ViewModelProvider.Factory` & instantiate your `ViewModel` with constructor parameter. Example: https://medium.com/koderlabs/viewmodel-with-viewmodelprovider-factory-the-creator-of-viewmodel-8fabfec1aa4f

Answer (score 0):

`intent` is shorthand for the `getIntent()` function on the `Activity` class. Your view model can't access it, and it probably shouldn't be dealing with `Intent`s anyway. Just pass the number you want into the function:

```
fun loadAllQuestions(type: Int) {
    // treating type == 0 as the default
    val jsonStr = "${if (type == 1) "mcq2" else "mcq1"}.json".loadJSONFromAsset()
}
```

or better, make an enum with some meaningful names for each type

```
enum class QuestionType(val filename: String) {
    COOL("mcq1.json"), HARD("mcq2.json")
}
```

and use those, so you're not dealing with magic numbers and it's clearer what's happening

```
fun loadAllQuestions(type: QuestionType) {
    // no need for a default, you can only pass in valid values now
    val jsonStr = type.filename.loadJSONFromAsset()
}
```

then in the activity, you can check your `Intent`, work out which `QuestionType` your number relates to, and pass it into the `loadAllQuestions` call. You can even use the enum value directly instead of an `Int` with `put/getSerializableExtra` if you like!

---

I added a default result instead of using null if the number isn't valid, but if you do want nulls, you can do this:

```
fun loadAllQuestions(type: Int) {
    val jsonStr = when(type) {
        0 -> "mcq1.json"
        1 -> "mcq2.json"
        else -> null
    }?.run { loadJSONFromAsset() } // only runs if the result isn't null
}
```

or

```
// nullable param now, in case there's no valid value in your extra
fun loadAllQuestions(type: QuestionType?) {
    // defaults to null if type is null
    val jsonStr = type?.filename?.loadJSONFromAsset()
}
```